# Compare LocalDate with LocalDateTime in HQL/JPQL

Tags: hibernate, spring-data-jpa, spring-data, hql, jpql

Is it possible to compare `LocalDate` with `LocalDateTime` in HQL/JPQL? This is my query of repository method in spring data which should return amount of orders per required dates. The field `deliveryDateTime` in Order entity has type `LocalDateTime`. I want to ignore time part and compare only date part.

```java
@Query("SELECT new OrderCountPerDate(DATE(o.deliveryDateTime), COUNT(o.id)) FROM Order o WHERE DATE(o.deliveryDateTime) IN :dates GROUP BY DATE(o.deliveryDateTime) ")
List<LocalDate> findValidOrderDates(List<LocalDate> dates);
```

My current code gives me this error:

```
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.QueryException: No data type for node: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.tree.MethodNode 
     \-[METHOD_CALL] MethodNode: '('
        +-[METHOD_NAME] IdentNode: 'DATE' {originalText=DATE}
```

It looks like DATE method doesn't exist. So, is there other way how to do it?

Comment: Since `DATE` is not known HQL/JPQL function you got this error. You can try to define appropriate function in your hibernate dialect and then use it. What database do you use? What database type does the column `deliveryDateTime` have?

Comment: @SternK I am using postgres and for LocalDateTime I have timestamp type

Answer (score 0):

So, you should create a custom dialect in the following way:

```java
import org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL10Dialect;
import org.hibernate.dialect.function.StandardSQLFunction;
import org.hibernate.type.LocalDateType;
import org.hibernate.type.StandardBasicTypes;

public class MyDialect extends PostgreSQL10Dialect
{

   public MyDialect()
   {
      registerFunction( "my_date", new StandardSQLFunction( "date", LocalDateType.INSTANCE ) );
   }
}
```

Set this dialect in your `application.properties`:

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=com.me.MyDialect
```

And then you can use the `my_date` function in your HQL/JPQL queries:

```java
@Query("select new com.me.OrderCountPerDate(my_date(o.deliveryDateTime), count(o.id)) from Order o where my_date(o.deliveryDateTime) in :dates group by my_date(o.deliveryDateTime) ")
List<OrderCountPerDate> findValidOrderDates(List<LocalDate> dates);
```