# Spring Data JPA query records by hour minute only without secs

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

We can query records by hour minute only without secs in mysql like below in where condition:

```
DATE_FORMAT(ecs.scheduler_date, '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i') = DATE_FORMAT('2020-10-17 16:12:15', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%i')
```

But how to write in Spring Data JPA ?

Comment: You can declare the `DATE_FORMAT` function in your custom hibernate dialect and then use it in your jpql/hql. See for example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63712259/6277104).

Answer (score 0):

In repository pass this as custom query in the below specified way

```
@Query(value="SELECT DATE_FORMAT(datetime,'%y-%m-%d %H:%i') as Day
FROM table1 GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(datetime,'%y-%m-%d %H:%i')",nativeQuery = true)
List<Entity_class_name> methodname();
```

In the same query if needed to pass a specific value then you can replace them like ?1.. in the query instead of variables and inside methodname() pass the values as arguments. Example below

```
@Query(value="select * from ?1 where name=?2",nativeQuery=true)
List method(tablename, name);
```